# Как экспортировать размер, цвет столбца и строки из DBGridEh в шаблон Excel

Tags: delphi, база-данных, excel

Много перечитал форумов, но ответа на свой вопрос не нашел. Заключается он в следующем: можно ли передать размер, цвет столбца и строки, проще говоря таблицу с определенным форматирование из DBGridEh в шаблон Excel ?

Код процедуры экспорта:

```
procedure TExcelView.ProcessMultipleRecords(Sheet: Variant; Row: integer; DataSet: TDataSet);
var i,z,y: integer;
ArrayData : Variant;
FieldName: string;
FieldList: TStringList;
StartCol: integer;
Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Range,RowRange: OleVariant;
begin
  StartCol:=0;
  FieldList:=TStringList.Create;
  for i:=2 to Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count do begin
    FieldName:=string(Sheet.Cells[Row,i]);
    if DataSet.FindField(FieldName) <> nil then begin
    FieldList.Add(FieldName);
    if StartCol=0 then StartCol:=i;
    end else if StartCol <> 0 then FieldList.Add('');
  end;
  FieldList.Text:=Trim(FieldList.Text);
  DataSet.Last;
  DataSet.First;
  ArrayData := VarArrayCreate([1, DataSet.RecordCount, 1, FieldList.Count], varVariant);
  y := 1;
  while not DataSet.Eof do
  begin
z := 1;
for i := 0 to FieldList.Count-1 do begin
  if FieldList[i]='' then ArrayData[y, z] :=''
  else  begin
    if DataSet.FieldByName(FieldList[i]).DataType=ftFloat then
      ArrayData[y, z] := DataSet.FieldByName(FieldList[i]).AsFloat
    else ArrayData[y, z] := DataSet.FieldByName(FieldList[i]).Value;
  end;
  inc(z);
end;
    DataSet.Next;
    inc(y);
  end;
  for i := 1 to DataSet.RecordCount-1 do
Sheet.Rows[Row+1].Insert;
  Cell1 := Sheet.Cells[Row, StartCol];
  Cell2 := Sheet.Cells[Row, StartCol + FieldList.Count-1];
  Cell3 := Sheet.Cells[Row + DataSet.RecordCount-1, StartCol + FieldList.Count-1];
  RowRange := Sheet.Range[Cell1, Cell2];
  Range := Sheet.Range[Cell1, Cell3];
  if DataSet.RecordCount=0 then RowRange.Value:='' else begin
    RowRange.AutoFill(Range, 3);
    Range.WrapText:= True;
    Range.VerticalAlignment := 1;
    Range.Value := ArrayData;
  end;
  FieldList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: А в чем, собственно, вопрос? Как получить цвет столбца из DBGrid? Или как указать цвет для Excel Column?

Comment: @kami Собственно, эти два вопроса меня и интересуют)

Comment: Не понимаю, за что вопрос набирает плюсы, по отдельности обе его части находятся очень легко: цвет столбца в DBGridEx - в документации EhLib `DbGrid.Columns.Items[i].Color` (там же - `Font`, `Width` и все остальное). Выставление параметов ячейкам в Excel - примеров куча, частично они есть и у вас в коде, но не с нужными свойствами. Вам требуются `Range.Font.Color` и `Range.Width`. Осталось только соединить это в цикле в имеющемся коде, после заполнения ячеек данными. Если у кого есть желание - можно оформить как ответ :)